# How do I find the minimum value of n if value of $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$ and r is known?

Tags: factorial

Let

$x = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$

If the value of x and r is known to me how do I find the minimum value of n that will satisfy the equation? I tried simplifying the equation by plugging in

$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}\ =\ (n-r+1)\ *\ (n-r+2)\ ....\ *\ n$

This will result in a polynomial equation but since the value of r can be quite large the degree of this polynomial equation can be very high, how am I supposed to proceed from here?

Comment: I guess you may try to find a prime factorization of factorials and $x$. And compare it.

Comment: You said the value of $x$ and $r$ are known and you want to find the minimum value of $r$.  I think you mean either the value of $x$ and $n$ are known and you want $r$, or the value of $x$ and $r$ are known and you want $n$.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad! I need minimum value of n when n!/(n-r)! and r is known.

Comment: If $r\ne 0$ then $f(n)=n!/(n-r)!$ (for $\min(n,n-r)\geq 0$) is strictly increasing if $r>0 $ and strictly decreasing if $r<0$ and there is at most one $n$ for which $f(n)=x.$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2345968/inverting-binomial-coefficients

Comment: for the record, $n$ is unique in that case, it can me minumum often different than a maximum if $x$ is given, $r,n$ to be guessed.